# What are the algebraic normal forms for each bit of $z$, where $z = (x \oplus y) \oplus ((x \wedge y) \ll 1)$ (a non-linear operation in NORX)?

Tags: implementation

Let $x, y, z$ denote three $n$-bit words such that $$z = (x \oplus y) \oplus ((x \land y) \ll 1).$$

The NORX paper contains the generalized description of the algebraic normal forms for each bit of $x$ given $y$ and $z$: $$\begin{array}{l}
x_0 = (z_0 \oplus y_0),\\
x_1 = (z_1 \oplus y_1) \oplus (x_0 \land y_0),\\
\vdots\\
x_i = (z_i \oplus y_i) \oplus (x_{i-1} \land y_{i-1}),\\
\vdots\\
x_{n-1} = (z_{n-1} \oplus y_{n-1}) \oplus (x_{n-2} \land y_{n-2}),
\end{array}$$

where $w_i$ denotes an $i$-th bit of the word $w \in \{x, y, z\}$.

What is the corresponding generalized description of the algebraic normal forms for each bit of $z$ given $x$ and $y$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From
$$x_i = z_i \oplus y_i \oplus (x_{i-1} \land y_{i-1})$$
we get
$$z_i = x_i \oplus y_i \oplus (x_{i-1} \land y_{i-1}).$$

Comment: Then I am wondering why the paper claims that this function "is not obviously invertible at a first glance". Is it true that it is a triangular [T-function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-function) (as well as addition and subtraction)?

Comment: It is triangular, but there is no word-based expression for inversion like for addition/subtraction. Probably that's the reason.

Comment: It seems that the inverse of H function in NORX is triangular, but the H function itself is not triangular because the algebraic normal form for $z_i$  does _not_ depend on every single less significant bit. Is it true?

Comment: That is correct; not having an inverse with a similar number of word operations as the forward direction is why we called it "not obvious". Both the forward and backward directions are T-functions; a T-function does not need to involve every previous bit to be triangular, it just needs to involve _exclusively_ previous bits.

Comment: @SamuelNeves: "a T-function does not need to involve every previous bit to be triangular" — it depends on what is meant by the word "involve". According to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-function), "if every single less significant bit is included in the update of every bit in the state, such a T-function is called triangular." Note the phrasing: "every single less significant bit". [1/2]

Comment: @SamuelNeves: The backward direction of H function matches the definition of "triangular", but the forward direction does not because the ANF for an $i$-th bit of the word $x$ (i.e. backward direction) contains $x_{i-1}$, but the ANF for an $i$-th bit of the word $z$ (i.e. forward direction) does not contain $z_{i-1}$. Is my understanding of "triangularity" correct? [2/2]

Comment: It seems a bit silly to me to be talking about triangular T-functions, since the T already stands for triangular. I don't quite know where the wikipedia article got that definition from, since I don't recall seeing it in literature.

Comment: @SamuelNeves: Section 4 in the paper "A New Class of Invertible Mappings" [A. Klimov, A. Shamir] gives a description of what the name "T-function" refers to, and explains the difference between the implicit triangulation and the explicit triangulation... So maybe a "triangular T-function" implies a "T-function which has an explicit triangular shape"?

Comment: OK, as far as I can tell Wikipedia has a much more restricted definition of a T-function, which forces it to be invertible (this is not necessarily the case). What it calls a T-function is what one would ordinarily call an invertible or bijective T-function, and what it calls a triangular T-function is what one would call a single-cycle T-function. So, the NORX op is a bijective T-function, but definitely not a single-cycle T-function (when fixing one of the arguments).